# Unable to "Leave closed" for another close reason in the reopen queue

Tags: bug

I am reviewing a question in the Reopen queue. I think the original close reason (opinion-based) was resolved, but there is now another issue. I followed these steps:

1. "Leave closed"
2. "Submit"
3. "This question doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline"
4. "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"
5. "Keep closed"

-> error message appears: "You must select a reason before submitting."

I tried to repeat the steps for the same question, but the error message appeared every time. After pressing "Back" in the final window, I found that clicking "This question doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline" did not mark the radio button as selected.

I am using Firefox.

[image]